# Javascript that detects Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

What's a surefire way of detecting whether a user has Firebug enabled?

Comment: just as an aside : what do you need that for? To know if you can write to the firebug's console or what?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

## Original answer:

Check for the `console` object (created only with Firebug), like such:

```
if (window.console && window.console.firebug) {
  //Firebug is enabled
}
```

---

## Update (January 2012):

The Firebug developers have [decided to remove `window.console.firebug`](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4772). You can still detect the presence of Firebug by [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) like

```
if (window.console && (window.console.firebug || window.console.exception)) {
  //Firebug is enabled
}
```

or [various other approaches](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4772#c8) like

```
if (document.getUserData('firebug-Token')) ...
if (console.log.toString().indexOf('apply') != -1) ...
if (typeof console.assert(1) == 'string') ...
```

but in general, there should be no need to actually do so.

Comment: Remember, use your powers for good, or awesome, but don't penalize firebug users because it makes it so easy to circumnavigate any sort of 'copy' or 'save' actions they might be interested in taking. That'd be bad form.

Comment: IIRC, using console.log in Safari with developer mode on also works - so the statement 'created only with firebug' *may* be incorrect.

Comment: Safari indeed has a console object, but Safari's console does not have a `firebug` property, and thus the above condition will fail in Safari, thus not detecting Firebug

Comment: i've just implemented this and it is a really good idea to seperate developers from regular users on your site.  for example, letting them know about an API you have available for them to use!

Comment: @Luc: You mean developers who happen to be using Firefox with Firebug installed.

Answer (score 20):

If firebug is enabled, window.console will not be undefined. console.firebug will return the version number.

Answer (score 9):

As of Firebug version 1.9.0, `console.firebug` is no longer defined because of privacy concerns; see [release notes](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Release_Notes#Firebug_1.9), [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4772). **This breaks the above mentioned methods.** Indeed, it changes the answer to Allan's question to "there is no way"; if there *is* another way, it's considered a bug.

The solution instead is to check for the availability of `console.log` or whatever it is you want to use or replace.

Here is a suggestion for a replacement for the kind of code that David Brockman is presenting above, but one that doesn't remove any existing functions.

```
(function () {
    var names = ['log', 'debug', 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'assert', 'dir', 'dirxml', 
                'group', 'groupEnd', 'time', 'timeEnd', 'count', 'trace', 'profile', 'profileEnd'];

    if (window.console) {
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (!window.console[names[i]]) {
                window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
            }
        }
    } else {
        window.console = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: I edited the original answer and added new, working detection methods

Answer (score 4):

It may be impossible to detect.

Firebug has multiple tabs, which may be disabled separately, and, are now not enabled by default.

GMail as it is can only tell whether or not I have the "console" tab enabled. Probing further than this would likely require security circumvention, and you don't want to go there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this to prevent firebug calls in your code from causing errors if it's not installed.

```
if (!window.console || !console.firebug) {
    (function (m, i) {
        window.console = {};
        while (i--) {
            window.console[m[i]] = function () {};
        }
    })('log debug info warn error assert dir dirxml trace group groupEnd time timeEnd profile profileEnd count'.split(' '), 16);
}
```

Comment: This is really bad style. For example, the Chrome developer console supports most (if not all) of these methods, but does not have console.firebug. Therefore, that code above disables perfectly working console methods in non-Firebug consoles, which sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind in Chrome window.console also returns true or [`Object console]`.

Furthermore, I would check whether Firebug is installed with

`if (window.console.firebug !== undefined) // firebug is installed`

Below is what I get in Safari and Chrome, no firebug installed.

```
if (window.console.firebug) // true
if (window.console.firebug == null) // true
if (window.console.firebug === null) // false
```

The Is-True and Is-Not Operators obviously do type coercion, which should be avoided in JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, to check whether something is defined, you should use “if (typeof window.console.firebug !== 'undefined')".

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the window.console.firebug has been removed by latest firebug version. because firebug is an extension based JavaScript debugger, Which defined some new function or object in window.console. So most times, you can only use this new defined functions to detection the  running status of firebug.

such as

```
if(console.assert(1) === '_firebugIgnore') alert("firebug is running!"); 
if((console.log+'''').indexOf('return Function.apply.call(x.log, x, arguments);') !== -1)  alert("firebug is running!");
```

You may test these approach in each firebug.

Best wishes!