# When using firebug, do I have to remove the console outputs when deploying?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am using firebug for debugging etc.

When I deploy, it seems as though I have to remove all the console.log statements from my javascript code?

When viewing on a browser that doesn't have firebug I am getting errors relating to console...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they will make IE error as IE does not have the console.

It's also good practice.

Comment: It seems error prone, to me. I like StuffMaster's solution better.

Comment: I mean it's simply good practice to remove debugging messages from any code before you deploy.

Answer (score 8):

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug) to create a log function. It will avoid those errors.

```
function log(string) {  
  if (window.console && window.console.firebug) {
    console.log(string);
  }
}
```

It's also easier to type :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding StuffMaster's answer: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781890/1132101) – `console.firebug` is no longer a valid method of checking for firebug availability.