# Is there a way to stop Firebug from working on a particular site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, firebug

Is there some way to make Firebug not work at all on a website?

Comment: You want to keep users from analyzing your site?  How, exactly, were you imagining that that might happen?

Comment: you could make your website look like a firebug console and hope that the user gets confused

Comment: I have no clue, hence why I asked

Comment: If you are trying to keep someone from viewing or reusing your Javascript, stop.

Comment: Bad idea. Stop it right there ...

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry: That was the best comment I have read all day

Comment: People shouldn't be voting this question down just because they don't like what it's asking. Downvotes are for bad/useless questions, not ones that you don't agree with.

Comment: Of course the real question is apparently "How can I keep people from viewing the .js files?"

Comment: @Chad: Vote to close is for questions that are objectively bad or useless.  Downvotes are for questions that shouldn't have been asked, but should be answered.

Comment: When I mouseover the downvote arrow, it says "This question is unclear or not useful". Neither of those conditions are satisfied here, it's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Chad: His REAL question wasn't clear from his post, and knowing the answer to this question is not useful to anyone.  (In fact, it might be harmful for some people to know the answer.)  What would you nominate as a question that ought to be downvoted, but not closed?

Comment: Well, personally I never downvote questions. But that's probably because my rep is high enough to be able to vote to close. I downvote *answers* when they're wrong, but there's not really any way for a question to be "wrong". I mostly see downvotes used by people who have 100 <= rep < 3000, as a way of drawing attention to a question that should be closed. I don't know about others, but I tend to click on questions with negative scores just to see if they need to be closed.

Comment: And I'd disagree that the answer isn't useful to anyone. The answer is useful to anyone that has the same question: "is it possible to stop people from viewing my Javascript (through Firebug or any other method)?"

Comment: I upvoted because this is a great question. The more people that learn the answer is "no", the fewer people will try it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the performance of your website suffers when Firebug is enabled, you may want to display a warning, asking users to switch it off. [You can easily detect if Firebug is enabled through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug).

Comment: +1, this is probably all your site can do. In addition you could try to log which users have it enabled, if it will cause your page to run slow, etc. At least then if they complain you can say, "well, if you had turned off firebug like we asked you to..."

Answer (score 15):

WARNING: EXTREME EVIL.  NEVER EVER USE THIS CODE.  Also, it won't deter someone who is resourceful.

```
setTimeout(checkForFirebug, 100);
function checkForFirebug()
{
    if (window.console && window.console.firebug) {
      while(true);    //Firebug is enabled
    }
    setTimeout(checkForFirebug, 100);
}
```

**EDIT:** I figured I would provide an answer to the real question behind the question.  The fact is, Javascript is an interpreted language and that interpreter is in the browser.  This makes it literally impossible to provide Javascript that is both secure and runnable.  The same goes for HTML and CSS.  The best you can do is minify the Javascript to make it a little less easy to reuse.  If the company in question really wants "secure" Javascript, you just have to tell them it's not truly possible.

Comment: I dont know whether to + or - this level of evil.

Comment: The easy workaround for this is to disable javascript before you load the page.  This doesn't actually secure your code, but it may piss off your users.  So like most evil things, it's also very stupid.

Comment: Another workaround for this is to put `javascript:checkForFirebug=function(){}` in the URL bar before opening Firebug

Answer (score 10):

Ummm....
What does using Firefox (with or without Firebug) have to do with this?

I use IE and I can just as easily view your JavaScript. Likewise with Google Chrome. Hell, I can download your JavaScript when viewing your webpage on my Palm Treo.

Anything which can be accessed directly from a browser can be downloaded and analyzed at leisure. As others have said (better than I), JavaScript which runs on your website should be considered to be "open source". Find another way to do it (i.e. processing on your server) or accept that someone will hack in and look at it.

Mind you, are your routines so obviously good (in terms of what they do to your webpages) that a user will go to your website and immediately say "Hey, this is cool, I wonder how they do it?" If not, don't worry about it - most people won't be interested enough to try to look at your JavaScript.

You could try minifying your JavaScript, but that's not 100% going to stop someone who's determined. You could try encrypting it, but I've never tried. Or put a copyright notice in your JavaScript files, so at least someone else won't be able to subsequently pass off your work as yours without getting into legal trouble.

Answer (score 7):

No.  Nobody wants your javascript routines anyway.  :-)

And if you're worried about unsecure code, you should rewrite your site to be secure instead of trying to hide its problems.

Comment: "My javascript routines" belong to the company I work for and my company wants the stuff we develop secured. No offence to you but your reply is both pretty useless and pretty arrogant.

Comment: @William: tell your company that if they want something "secured", they should not put it on a public webpage.

Comment: I was sincere in my offer of a useful perspective on a misinformed pursuit of "your company", erm, clueless app-dev managers.  But no offense taken.

Comment: Besides, I put a smiley face!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to hide your HTML/CSS/JavaScript from visitors, that is not possible. Even if one cannot use Firebug, one can simply view the HTML source code. Any external JavaScripts and stylesheets can be downloaded as the plain text files they are. Because HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are *client-side* technologies, that are downloaded as plain text and interpreted by the web browser, it is theoretically *impossible* to hide your code. The best thing you can do to make the code *harder* to understand, is to *obfuscate* it. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscator).

Answer (score 6):

You could click on the `Off` button to disable it.

Or are you trying to prevent your users from running it? If so, good luck...

Answer (score 5):

> "My javascript routines" belong to the company I work for and my company wants the stuff we develop secured.

You do not *secure* stuff by lightly patting "hackers" on the fingers when they use one specific debugging tool. Try to prevent them from using the ultimate *hacker tool*: "View Source".

If it's out there it's out there. "Secure" means something different in this context. It means securing whatever important data you have by employing techniques that are impenetrable* even with full knowledge of the source code. The source code itself is not securable, and neither does it need to be.

---

*) "impenetrable" = difficult enough to subvert in a reasonable amount of time, nothing is 100% :)

Answer (score 4):

Anything you send to the client, all your javascript, is open to whoever you send it to.  Don't have anything there that you don't want people to see.  There is no way to prevent someone else's browser from using Firebug, or a lot of other tools, to analyze your code.  You could try to make your html, css, and javascript *really bad*, and that might slow them down!  There are obfuscation programs to make it difficult to read.  If you want to hide functionality, you'll need to have it happen on the server.

Answer (score 4):

You could develop your site in Flash, Silverlight, or Java. Firebug will then be limited to displaying your base HTML.

I'm assuming you're worried about reverse engineering with FireBug.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, I need everything to be fully HTML. The sites I develop don't belong to me, but to the company I work for, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

No, of course not.  If Firebug is revealing something that you must prevent your users from seeing, then you are approaching this problem completely wrong.  I am not trying to be rude or degrading, but attempting to block one particular program in an effort to fix a bug in your web application is about as logical as a bucket of steam.  Firebug does nothing magical; I can do anything it does by writing some code.  Having said that, there must be an underlying issue that you should be more concerned about.

Comment: I never mentioned anything about bugs, my question is simple and straightforward. The underlying issue is that my company requested that any javascript code we develop is secured.

Comment: @William No offense, but then your company needs to get a better grip on what "secure" means in this context.

Comment: You can not secure Javascript, only obscure it.

Comment: @William I don't know what your definition of straight-forward is, but your question literally screams **THERE'S MORE TO THE STORY**.  Now I have a question.  What does Firebug have to do with the "security" of your Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a little trick that i use helps lower people seeing your code,

One of the tricks i do that does not prevent the JavaScript from being found by the experianced developer or hacker, but deters the few people playing with Firebug / inspector,

use jQuery or another lib with a grate selector

the second port of call is all you files put them into a loader file E.G

**Loader.js**

```
(function($){
    function loader(type, addr){
        var head = $("head")[0];
        switch(type){
            case "script":{
                var element = $(document.createElement("script"));
                element.attr("type", "text/javascript");
                element.attr("src", addr);
                element.attr("loaded", "loader")
                $(head).append(element);
            }
            case "style":{
                var element = $(document.createElement("link"));
                element.attr("rel", "stylesheet");
                element.attr("type", "text/css");
                element.attr("loaded", "loader");
                element.attr("href", addr);
                $(head).append(element);
            }
        }
    }

    loader("css", "path/to/your.css");
    loader("script", "path/to/script.js");

    loader("script", "unloader.js")
})(jQuery);
```

So to start with were using a closure this prevent anyone from using the console input of the inspector to see the code that has been run.

so once this file has been passed it will load your CSS and JS but you can still see there loaded in the head element of your inspector, thanks to browsers and the they way they work you can remove and not unload them this means the code will not be removed from execution but will prevent them being shown in the inspector this is what goes in the unloader.

**unloader.js**

```
(function($){
    $("head *[loaded=loader]").remove();
})(jQuery);
```

The above will remove the the files loaded though the loader.

The only thing you need to remember is to add `loaded="loader"` to your scrip that that includes the loader, now this does not make it impossible for some one to see your files but stops the inspector from showing them in the HTML,

the ways around this can be to "View Source" code see the loader file and read that so make sure you minimize the code i use Google Closure Compiler (http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)

even this does not stop them it just make it more difficult. one of the steps i have tested but dont use is on the loader and files your loading use a .HTAccess rule to check that they have a reffer link form your site this will prevent them browsing directly to your js/css code files

another tip don't store them in normal places and don't use common names E.G scripts in /scripts/ CSS in /style/ or style.css

Here is an example of the loader Closure Compiled then Obfuscated

**Loader.js**

```
var _0xc596=["\x68\x65\x61\x64","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x73\x72\x63","\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x64","\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64","\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B","\x72\x65\x6C","\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x73\x68\x65\x65\x74","\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x63\x73\x73","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65","\x63\x73\x73","\x70\x61\x74\x68\x2F\x74\x6F\x2F\x79\x6F\x75\x72\x2E\x63\x73\x73","\x70\x61\x74\x68\x2F\x74\x6F\x2F\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x2E\x6A\x73","\x75\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x6A\x73"];(function (_0x76e5x1){function _0x76e5x2(_0x76e5x2,_0x76e5x3){var _0x76e5x4=_0x76e5x1(_0xc596[0])[0];switch(_0x76e5x2){case _0xc596[1]:var _0x76e5x5=_0x76e5x1(document[_0xc596[2]](_0xc596[1]));_0x76e5x5[_0xc596[5]](_0xc596[3],_0xc596[4]);_0x76e5x5[_0xc596[5]](_0xc596[6],_0x76e5x3);_0x76e5x5[_0xc596[5]](_0xc596[7],_0xc596[8]);_0x76e5x1(_0x76e5x4)[_0xc596[9]](_0x76e5x5);;case _0xc596[15]:_0x76e5x5=_0x76e5x1(document[_0xc596[2]](_0xc596[10]));_0x76e5x5[_0xc596[5]](_0xc596[11],_0xc596[12]);_0x76e5x5[_0xc596[5]](_0xc596[3],_0xc596[13]);_0x76e5x5[_0xc596[5]](_0xc596[7],_0xc596[8]);_0x76e5x5[_0xc596[5]](_0xc596[14],_0x76e5x3);_0x76e5x1(_0x76e5x4)[_0xc596[9]](_0x76e5x5);;} ;} ;_0x76e5x2(_0xc596[16],_0xc596[17]);_0x76e5x2(_0xc596[1],_0xc596[18]);_0x76e5x2(_0xc596[1],_0xc596[19]);} )(jQuery);
```

**unloader.js**

```
var _0xc2fb=["\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65","\x68\x65\x61\x64\x20\x2A\x5B\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x64\x3D\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x5D"];(function (_0x3db3x1){_0x3db3x1(_0xc2fb[1])[_0xc2fb[0]]();} )(jQuery);
```

to reproduce of to: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home put your code in under the // ADD YOUR CODE HERE

Then the result that is given back use: http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx to make it even more unreadable.

Hope this helps any one else looking to make the JS as Secure as possible

But please remember as every one else has said this will not stop the pro hackers just make it very difficult to read and understand

Comment: After this i decided to post a full guide on my blog check it out: http://blog.123torrentz.com/2012/06/prevent-firebug-or-inspectors-from.html

Answer (score 1):

No...............

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, no, as the browser (in this case firefox) on their machine can choose to run whatever javascript (such as firebug) it wants to.  You cannot prevent users from running it along with your website.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to protect your code, you could try encrypting your javascript source code

[google encrypt javascript source](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&rlz=1R2GGIC_enGB358&q=encrypt+javascript+code&aq=1&aqi=g5g-m3&aql=&oq=encrypt+javascr&gs_rfai=)

Comment: Note that encryption can be defeated by someone pretending to be a browser (possibly using rhino).

Comment: correct, it will only make it a bit more difficult to get to, but ultimately if a pc can display it/read it/use it someone will be able to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is too low to comment, but I just wanted to point out something that I noticed after learning about window.history.pushState();   it seems that you can change what is currently in the address bar, and once you do that, "view page source" doesn't work.  So if there was a way to block developer tools from working, I wouldn't know how to view the source code.

EDIT:  After using window.history.pushState(), when I view developer tools, it tells me to reload the page to view what is in a javascript file (but then again it does show the address to the JS file so that doesn't help much)