# Disable firebug from mozilla and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to stop Firebug from working on a particular site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877663/is-there-a-way-to-stop-firebug-from-working-on-a-particular-site)

Can I disable firebug form all browsers by using some javascript, jquery,
or php script. If yes then please describe how I can do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Firebug is a Firefox extension :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario firebug is an extension for all browsers by way of a bookmarklet. :)

Comment: @user1109732 why would you want to do this? If you're trying to stop people from stealing your code/html/javascript/whatever then forget it. There's hundreds of ways I could steal your code/javascript without even thinking about Firebug!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't, firebug is a extension of the browser and you don't have access to the extension manager from js.

You can check if the console is active, for ff the fastest way is

```
if('console' in window)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can detect firebug using

> if (window.console && window.console.firebug) 
>   {   //Firebug is enabled }

[Javascript that detects Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug)

but you can not disable the firebug from the browser through your file