# How to check whether firebug is installed in Mozilla or not?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript that detects Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug)

How to check whether Firebug is installed in Mozilla or not using JavaScript code?

Comment: That depends on what your purpose is - logging thru fbug? Then checking for console.log might be enough (note that there are also other tools that define console.log). Preventing disassembly? Then please don't, not everyone who *has* fbug is trying to break your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anywhere in a web page, you could do this:

```
<script>
if(console) {
    console.log("Firebug is installed and running!");
} else {
    alert("Firebus either isn't installed, or isn't running.");
}
</script>
```

Not perfect if you specifically want to check for Firebug, because it could report that Firebug exists on other browsers such as Chrome, since their Developer Tools also use the same `console` object as Firebug. If you really need to only check for Firebug, then you could also add a browser detection to make sure you're in Firefox.

Comment: This will throw an exception if console doesn't exist. Either `if (window.console)` or `if (typeof console !== 'undefined')` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn’t detect Firebug at all, it just detects if a `console` object is available.

If you want to detect Firebug, look for `window.console.firebug`. Use [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug/398120#398120):

```
if (window.console && console.firebug) {
  // Firebug is enabled
}
```