# Right way to detect firebug on the client side when firebug is activated on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript that detects Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug)

I tried the following code which did not work.

```
if(window.console && window.console.firebug)
{
 alert("Firebug active!");
}
```

What is the right way to detect firebug on the client side when firebug is activated on a webpage using JavaScript or JQuery.

Comment: Try using || operator instead of &&.

Comment: @JanHocevar your comment makes no sense. Then it would alert that Firebug was active if `window.console` were defined.