# Firebug (firefox) injections on Pagemethods(webservices)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

While I was developing some web apps, to me it became optimal to use a web service  to interact with the server, and the rest I was enjoying to do with client side (JQuery). but when I was testing my code, I encountered a huuge hole in it, and i don't know how to prevent it.

The problem is that I can easily inject javascript and run any functions including webmethods from firefox's firebug tool.Is it a something known, and what should be done to prevent it.
THank you

Comment: You do not even need a browser to interact with your server, that is why serverside validation is key.

Comment: if you want to stop firebug Read this , not sure if its still relevant- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug

Comment: In what way do you feel this is a huge hole? A security hole? Stability problem? What might somebody do with this capability that you feel would cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a hole at all.  The client can only run JavaScript code on the page that they have downloaded from you on their own computer.  It has no affect on your site at all.

As for the ability for them to make requests via JavaScript -- well, they can make requests via the browser too.  What's the difference?  Just make sure that your server properly validates all requests -- it should treat any request as if it were as malicious as possible.

Comment: Thank you, I need to reconsider the way I program :)